# Unknown error: Error: No valid exports main found for 'C:\Users\UTKARSH SRIVASTAVA\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\uuid'

Tags: angular, laravel

Trying to install angular using cli but when I use this **ng new foldername** it gives the message.

**Unknown error: Error: No valid exports main found for 'C:\Users\UTKARSH SRIVASTAVA\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules@angular\cli\node_modules\uuid'**

please let me know where I'm wrong because previously in installed this using the same command and it's working but today it's can't please help me.

Thanks in advance

[image]

Comment: I've got the same issue.  Seems to be an issue caused by the Angular 10 CLI that hasn't been documented.

Comment: @Mocolicious sir....thanks for your reply!

Comment: if you have Node.js 13.5.0 upgrade it

Comment: Upgrading to 14.x versions fixed it for me

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just Update your node to current version v14.5.0 and reinstall angular "npm install -g@angular/cli".problem will be solved